# Javascript createElement does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code which works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work on IE

```
<script>
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/")
    element.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
    element.setAttribute("download", "")
    element.click();
    element.remove();
</script>`
```

Neither

```
<script>
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/")
    element.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
    element.click();
    element.remove();
</script>`
```

Comment: `download` attribute will not works in `IE`

Comment: I have seen this earlier, but after removing `download` attribute it's not working in IE

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually put `element` into document to make this work. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0gw0ggmb/3/).

```
var element = document.createElement("a");

element.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/")
element.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
element.setAttribute("download", "")
document.body.appendChild(element); //<- append to body
element.click();
element.remove();
```

But anyway this wont make `download` attribute to work.